# Return const float* problems

Tags: c++

Hello i'm very new to C++ and have run into quite a problem, so i have written a simple function to return a players x, y & z origin, here it is:

```
float Orgx, Orgy, Orgz;
const float* ReturnORG(Vector3 Blah)
{
    float Orgx = Blah.x;
    float Orgy = Blah.y;
    float Orgz = Blah.z;

    return (float)((Orgx), (Orgx), (Orgx));
}
```

the problem is that i get an error saying:

```
"Error: return value type doesn't match function type"
```

I Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to return a raw pointer? A `Vector3` looks much more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the comma operators, `(float)((Orgx), (Orgx), (Orgx))` is equivalent to `(float)Orgx`. `float` doesn't match `float*`, so the error occured.

You should want to allocate array statically

```
const float* ReturnORG(Vector3 Blah)
{
    static float Org[3];
    Org[0] = Org[1] = Org[2] = Blah.x;

    return Org;
}
```

or dynamically

```
const float* ReturnORG(Vector3 Blah)
{
    float *Org = new float[3];
    Org[0] = Org[1] = Org[2] = Blah.x;

    return Org;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!